# Text in hover change color just where the mouse is

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

How can I change the color of a text just where the mouse is and not in all the text?[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AX5Xw.png)

[image]

I want that the circle that you can see follow the mouse and on hover the text show just the border of the section of the letter that is in hover

I need an advice about which library or function I need to use?

Comment: This cant be done with HTML or JS.  Probably the only option would be to draw text on canvas, but that is quite complex issue.

Comment: Software recommendation questions are off-topic for reasons explained in #3 of [/help/on-topic](/help/on-topic).

Comment: You can get inspiration from [html-magnifier](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-magnifier?activeTab=readme) module in npm

Comment: I think a good bet would be to create a background with a gradient. Then use JS to set the origin point of this gradient to your mouse. Then put the text on top and use it as a mask only showing the background. Then you can make the gradient with a sharp edge from the text color let say black all around. and hover effect in white you make the center white.

Comment: They'll be existing solutions in SO - search for image hover / highlight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const fx = document.querySelector(".fx");

document.addEventListener("pointermove", e => {
  fx.style.top = e.clientY + "px";
  fx.style.left = e.clientX + "px";
  fx.querySelector("h1").style.transform = `translate(${(e.clientX - fx.getBoundingClientRect().width / 2) * -1}px, ${(e.clientY - fx.getBoundingClientRect().height / 2) * -1}px)`;
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
}

.container h1 {
  font-size: 10rem;
  color: red;
}

.container .fx {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  outline: 1px solid blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -100px;
  left: -100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: white;
}

.container .fx h1 {
  font-size: 10rem;
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 2px green;
  cursor: default;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>abc</h1>
  <div class="fx">
    <h1>abc</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

this is just a demo. this will need further logic if you implement this in your project. you will need some two-dimensional knowledge. it is kinda hard to explain in texts. i will not explain `css` because you might already know them. you will need two tags to hold the text (in demo is `h1`), one's for display and the other's for the effect (in the `fx` div). **important!** you need to the precise position/location in pixel of the `container` div and the `fx` background color need to be the same as the parent background color. to build the effect, you need to add `mousemove` event to the parent of the `container` (in demo is the `document`). make the `fx` div follows the cursor by setting the its `top` and `left` property to `e.clientY` and `e.clientX`. here is the hard part, when the `fx` div follows the cursor, the `h1` inside of it will follow along as well. the effect works when the `fx`'s `h1` stay still in place and stack on top of the `container`'s `h1`. to do it you need to `translate` the `fx`'s `h1` out of the `fx` by setting the `fx`'s `h1`'s translate to the cursor position subtraction the `container` position (`fx.querySelector("h1").style.transform = ...`). in the demo is easy because the `container` position is basically `x: 0` and `y: 0` and i just use `e.clientX * -1` and `e.clientY * -1`. i suggest you should copy and run the demo line by line to understand more.

#### Update

i've made improvement of the demo and make it more convenient to be implemented. to implement, just copy/paste and change `h1`'s `css` to your liking.

```js
const glass = document.querySelector(".magnifying-glass"),
    container = document.querySelector(".container"),
    cInfo = container.getBoundingClientRect();

document.addEventListener("pointermove", e => {
    glass.style.opacity = 1;
    glass.style.transform = `translate(
            ${e.clientX - cInfo.x - (glass.getBoundingClientRect().width / 2)}px, 
            ${e.clientY - cInfo.y - (glass.getBoundingClientRect().height / 2)}px
        )`;
    glass.querySelector("h1").style.transform = `translate(
            ${(e.clientX - (glass.getBoundingClientRect().width / 2) - cInfo.x) * -1}px, 
            ${(e.clientY - (glass.getBoundingClientRect().height / 2) - cInfo.y) * -1}px
        )`;
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
}

.container .display {
  font-size: 10rem;
  color: red;
}

.container .magnifying-glass {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  outline: 1px solid blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 0;
}

.container .magnifying-glass .magnify-fx {
  font-size: 10rem;
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 2px green;
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="display">abc</h1>
  <div class="magnifying-glass">
    <h1 class="magnify-fx">abc</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's perfect sir, very thank you. You can explain me how does this work? I'm a Jr. Front-end and I want to learn! Thank you

Comment: my apology, i was building the demo in a rush and didn't time to explain. i've updated my answer.